# writing long text to pdf using the PdfDocument class

Tags: android-studio

In my app, I have an option to export text to a PDF. To achieve this, I utilize the `PdfDocument` class, and everything works great. Recently, I even updated it to handle spanned text, and that also works seamlessly.

However, there's an issue when the length of the text exceeds the page size (minus the top and bottom margin). The text simply continues, and at the bottom, you can even see half a line (the top half of the line).

Below is the part of my code responsible for writing the (potentially) long text. For the sake of readability, I've omitted the section where I create an instance of the class, set the page size, and so forth.

```
        textPaint.typeface        = Typeface.create(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.NORMAL)
        textPaint.textSize        = cNormalSize
        textPaint.color           = ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.black)
        textPaint.isUnderlineText = false

        val spanText = Html.fromHtml(longHtmlText, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT)
        val staticLayout = StaticLayout.Builder
            .obtain(spanText, 0 , spanText.length, textPaint, mPageWidth - (2 * cLeftRightMargin))
            .setAlignment(Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL)
            .setLineSpacing(0f, 1.0f)
            .build()

        canvas.save()
        canvas.translate(cLeftRightMargin.toFloat(), mYPosOnPage.toFloat())
        staticLayout.draw(canvas)
        canvas.restore()
```

I am uncertain if the initialization of the `textPaint` is necessary yet (work in progress).

However, the questions are:

**How can I determine if the text (spanText) is longer than the available size?**

**How can I truncate the text at that point and print the remainder on the next page?**

I have been searching for a way to set the height somewhere, but have had no luck so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trying and dumps of my app i managed to find a solution.
sure you can use some library but i don't want this because it is more fun to learn how it works. So for all of you with the same mindset here how i solved it.

I have a first method in which i write a title to my page and after that i start with the long text. So in my first method i first write the title and then call a second method that will handle the long text as a recursive call.
The call to the second method is simply:

```
val spanText = Html.fromHtml(longHtmlText!!, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT)
page = printLongText(pageInfo, spanText, page, 1, mYPosOnPage)
```

the mYPosOnPage is the offset. On this first page it contains an offset to below my title. Within the method below i override this to the page margin for all pages after 1.
Then the recursive method that keeps calling itself with the remainder of the long text until nothing is left.

```
 private fun printLongText(pageInfo: PdfDocument.PageInfo,
                           spanText: Spanned,
                           page: PdfDocument.Page,
                           pageNr: Int,
                           yPos: Int): PdfDocument.Page
{
    var lPage: PdfDocument.Page = page
    var lLineCount = 34
    val textPaint = TextPaint()

    if (pageNr > 1) {
        // close previous and start new page
        mDocument.finishPage(lPage)            // close this page
        lPage = mDocument.startPage(pageInfo) // start new page
        lLineCount = 38                       // correct line count (no header so more space)
    }
    val canvas = lPage.canvas                 // init canvas

    textPaint.typeface        = Typeface.create(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.NORMAL)
    textPaint.textSize        = cNormalSize
    textPaint.color           = ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.black)
    textPaint.isUnderlineText = false

    // first build a static layout of the complete available text to determine which part fits the page
    var staticLayout = StaticLayout.Builder
        .obtain(spanText, 0 , spanText.length, textPaint, mPageWidth - (2 * cLeftRightMargin))
        .setAlignment(Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL)
        .setLineSpacing(0f, 1.0f)
        .setIncludePad(false)
        .build()

    // create a Rect for the available space
    val r = Rect(cLeftRightMargin, yPos, (mPageWidth- (2 * cLeftRightMargin)), mPageHeight - cTopBottomMargin - yPos )

    var lLastPos = try {
        staticLayout.getLineBounds(lLineCount, r)
        // we really do not care about the result of the above getLineBounds
        // we only care if it does or doesn't raise an exception
        // in case of an exception all the text is on this page and we are done.
        // in case of no exception there is more text after the lineCount
        staticLayout.getLineEnd(lLineCount)
    } catch ( e: Exception) {
        spanText.length
    }

    // sometimes GetLineEnd returns 0. if so all the remaining text fits
    if (lLastPos == 0) lLastPos = spanText.length

    // re-build the layout to contain only the part we want to print on this page
    staticLayout = StaticLayout.Builder
    .obtain(spanText, 0 , lLastPos, textPaint, mPageWidth - (2 * cLeftRightMargin))
    .setAlignment(Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL)
    .setLineSpacing(0f, 1.0f)
    .setIncludePad(false)
    .build()

    canvas.save()
    canvas.translate(cLeftRightMargin.toFloat(), yPos.toFloat())
    staticLayout.draw(canvas)
    canvas.restore()

    // check if we are done and if not do a recursive call to handle the remainder of the text
    if (lLastPos < spanText.length) {
        lPage = printLongText(pageInfo,
                              spanText.subSequence(lLastPos, spanText.length).toSpanned(),
                              lPage,
                              pageNr+1,
                              cTopBottomMargin
                             )
    }

    return lPage
}
```

Hope this helps others.
feel free to copy and use to your own liking.